# How Can I Run a Regex that Tests Text for Characters in a Particular Alphabet or Script?

Tags: regex, perl

I'd like to make a regex in Perl that will test a string for characters in a particular script. This would be something like:

```
$text =~ .*P{'Chinese'}.*
```

Is there a simple way of doing this, for English it's pretty easy by just testing for [a-zA-Z], but for a script like Chinese, or one of the Japanese scripts, I can't figure out any way of doing this short of writing out every character explicitly, which would make for some very ugly code. Ideas? I can't be the first/only person that's wanted to do this.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611425/how-to-count-the-chinese-word-in-a-file-using-regex-in-perl) seems helpful.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6937087/detect-chinese-character-using-perl#6939500

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at [perldoc perluniprops](http://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops.html), which provides an exhaustive list of properties you can use with `\p`. You’ll be interested in `\p{CJK_Unified_Ideographs}` and related properties such as `\p{CJK_Symbols_And_Punctuation}`. `\p{Hiragana}` and `\p{Katakana}` give you the kana. There is also a `\p{Script=...}` property for a number of scripts: `\p{Han}` and `\p{Script=Han}` match Han characters (Chinese), but there is no corresponding `\p{Script=Japanese}`, quite simply because Japanese has multiple scripts.

Comment: I thought [Hiragana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiragana) and [Katakana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katakana) were just used by in Japanese.

Comment: @ikegami: Right. The OP mentioned Japanese.

Comment: `\p{Kana_Supplement}` is incorrect and deprecated. It should be `\p{Block:KanaSupplement}` aka `\p{InKanaSupplement}`. The block only contains two defined characters, and they are either in Hiragana or Katakana as well. One needs not worry about this block.

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways of doing that. By block (`\p{Block=...}`) and by script (`\p{Script=...}`). The latter is probably more natural.

I don't know much about Chinese languages, but I think you want `\p{Script=Han}` aka `\p{Han}` for Chinese.

Japanese uses three scripts:

- Kanij: `\p{Script=Han}` aka `\p{Han}`
- Hiragana: `\p{Script=Hiragana}` aka `\p{Hiragana}` aka `\p{Hira}`
- Katakana: `\p{Script=Katakana}` aka `\p{Katakana}` aka `\p{Kana}`

You could take a look at [perluniprops](http://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops.html) to find the one you are looking for, or you could use `uniprops`* to find which properties match a specific character.

```
$ uniprops 4E2D
U+4E2D ‹中› \N{CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-4E2D}
    \w \pL \p{L_} \p{Lo}
    All Any Alnum Alpha Alphabetic Assigned InCJK_UnifiedIdeographs
    CJK_Unified_Ideographs L Lo Gr_Base Grapheme_Base Graph GrBase
    Han Hani ID_Continue IDC ID_Start IDS Ideo Ideographic Letter
    L_ Other_Letter Print UIdeo Unified_Ideograph Word XID_Continue
    XIDC XID_Start XIDS X_POSIX_Alnum X_POSIX_Alpha X_POSIX_Graph
    X_POSIX_Print X_POSIX_Word
```

To find out which characters are in a given property, you can use `unichars`*. (This is of limited usefulness since most CJK chars aren't named.)

```
$ unichars -au '\p{Han}'
 ⺀ U+2E80 CJK RADICAL REPEAT
 ⺁ U+2E81 CJK RADICAL CLIFF
 ⺂ U+2E82 CJK RADICAL SECOND ONE
 ⺃ U+2E83 CJK RADICAL SECOND TWO
 ⺄ U+2E84 CJK RADICAL SECOND THREE
 ⺅ U+2E85 CJK RADICAL PERSON
 ⺆ U+2E86 CJK RADICAL BOX
 ⺇ U+2E87 CJK RADICAL TABLE
 ⺈ U+2E88 CJK RADICAL KNIFE ONE
...
```

* — `uniprops` and `unichars` are available from the [Unicode::Tussle](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Unicode%3a%3aTussle) distro.