# javascript regex: how to single out english words AND non-english characters AND special characters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I'm working with string which contains both english and Chinese characters.
I want to single out each **english word** , **non-english characters** e.g. french, chinese etc., **numbers** and **special characters** e.g. "@#$%^&>?" for further manipulation.

So I tired

```
var nregex = /[^\u0000-\u007F]|[a-z]+|\d|[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]/ig
```

It works for most of the case, but I'm worried some special characters or emoji not included in the list of my code.

Is there an easier way other than list all special characters as I did?

Comment: Well, it is because `\S+` matches all what the previous branch matches. Did you try `/[\u00ff-\uffff]|[a-z]+/ig`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks! But this fails to include the numeric and other special characters such as 1,2,3,&,#,@,* etc.

Comment: Please provide some more sample inputs with exact expected output, as the question has become much less clear. Do you want to match `iloveyou` as 3 different words?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do word counts for a mixture of English and Chinese in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20396456/how-to-do-word-counts-for-a-mixture-of-english-and-chinese-in-javascript)

Comment: @PedroLobito: It looks like [that solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20396456/how-to-do-word-counts-for-a-mixture-of-english-and-chinese-in-javascript) does not work for OP, see the above comment.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32961117/797495

Comment: I suspect OP wants to read `iloveyou` as `i`, `love`, `you`, and thus some NLP package is required.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry for late response as I was working on the code. I don't need to cut "iloveyou" into three pieces, but my question has expanded to include all special characters and non-english characters. So I tried `var nregex = /[^\u0000-\u007F]|[a-z]+|\d|[!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]/ig` to do the work, but still worried if user typed in special character or imoji not included in the special character list.

Comment: Please update the question. I guess html tag does not have anything to do with it, add emoji if you care about them.

Comment: I've posted an answer that may help you.  Iit's not the perfect solution but will definitely work for your example.

Comment: why did you change you answer?! it's completely different from the original.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew just modified the question, but I don't know if it's OK to modified the question which is far away from the original question, since some people may had already involved with the original question.

Comment: Look, your original question was far from being clear. Now, it is still far from being clear. You should provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The regex you showed implies getting all the `[^\u0000-\u007F]` symbols, `[a-z]+` chunks, `\d` digits and then anything but these 3 (that is how I read it). So, you could try `[^\u0000-\u007F]|[a-z]+|\d|(?![^\u0000-\u007F]|[a-z\d]).`.

Comment: Well, what about [`/[^\u0000-\u007F]|[\u0000-\u0008\u0011\u0012\u0014-\u0019\u0021-\u007F]+/g`](https://regex101.com/r/qN9jI7/2)?

Comment: It works perfect with english, other languages and special characters.However the numbers are not selected with the code you helped with. How to modify it to include numbers? For example `abc123` would output ["abc",1,2,3] .  `1517` outputs [1,5,1,7], 123abc outputs [1,2,3,"abc"], `我爱你123` outputs [我,爱,你,1,2,3], `123我爱你` outputs [1,2,3,我,爱,你].

Comment: Where do I learn how unicode match to regex, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp could'nt help.

Answer (score 2):

Not the perfect solution, and you may need to tweak it,  but will work for the example given:

```js
string2 = "I love you 我爱你"
englishChars = string2.replace(/[^a-z ]/ig, "").trim().split(/\s+/);
nonEnglishChars = string2.replace(/[a-z ]/ig, "").split(/[ ]*/);
final = englishChars.concat(nonEnglishChars);
console.log(final);
```